# wordpress - proper foreach in array syntax

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm still very novice at PHP so any help is greatly appreciated. I'm using a custom menu to display 4 posts, and for each post I'd like the post thumbnail. My code is below, which gives me an invalid argument supplied error.

```
    <div id="stampnav">
    <?php $pages = wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header','theme_location' => 'stamp-menu' ) ); 
    foreach($pages as $pagg) {

    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pagg->ID, 'thumbnail'); }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: You might find better and quick answers at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call global $post and make a query to get the post thumbnail the menu will not return the meta associated with the page, it only queries the built in "menu" custom post type.

Your other option is to create a custom [Walker Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class) for your nav menu.

Comment: thank you, didn't realize thats how the custom menus worked. makes sense now, i'll give the walker a try

Comment: can you give me a hint with this? i'm getting an error on this part of my functions.php piece

`$item_output = $args->before;

$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';

$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', 

$item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

$item_output .= '</a>';

$item_output .= $args->after;



$thumbnail = '';

if( $id = has_post_thumbnail( (int)$item->object_id ) ) {
  $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $id )
  }
  
  $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );`